# Flex Library to do toaster style notifications?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

I'm building an Air app and one feature I need is toaster style notifications in the bottom right corner of the screen. Before I go ahead and start writing my own toast controller, does anyone know of an existing library for such functionality? I'm looking for something which will just manage displaying, hiding and stacking of toast notifications if I pass it a UIComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what toaster style notifications are.  But, I assume you mean, basically, "popups" right?  Similar to what TweetDeck does?

I don't know of a specific Library, but there used to be an Adobe AIR sample app that did this.  Here is [some documentation on it](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html).  That app did have a bug in multiple monitor systems if memory serves me.

Answer (score 2):

Funny, I'm working on this very thing.  Here's a library I found that you might find useful: http://code.google.com/p/as3notificationlib/  In the end that library didn't quite do what I wanted so I just created my own version, which was actually pretty easy.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library http://code.google.com/p/flex-toasterlib/ and it works very well.
Just make sure you set your top-level application's layout to "absolute" (for flex < 4) or "basicLayout" (for flex 4) in order to allow the notifications to be displayed on top of you display list.